# Heap Code Error

Tags: c, heap

I am getting an error in the following code. I am building a heap and for that I use the `buildup` and `move-up` functions whereas for deleting the values I use `move-down` and `deletion` functions. And for inserting the values I use `insert` function.

My output is showing error for the `deletion` part.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int a[100];
int size;
void display();
void moveup(int);
void insert(int);
void buildup();
int deletion();
void movedown(int);
int h;
void main()
{
    size=5;
    int i,j;
    printf("enter the elements\n");
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
       scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    a[0]=32767;
    printf("\n");
    buildup();
    display();
    insert(9);
    display();
    printf("\n after deletion\n");
    deletion();
    display();
}

void buildup()
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=size;i++)
        moveup(i);
}

void moveup(int i)
{
    int p,temp;
    temp=a[i];
    p=i/2;
    while(temp>a[p])
    {
        a[i]=a[p];
        i=p;
        p=i/2;
    }
    a[i]=temp;
 }

 void display()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=size;i++)
        printf("%3d\n",a[i]);
}

void insert(int t)
{
printf("\n after insertion\n");
    if(size==99)
printf("insertion not possible");
    a[++size]=t;
moveup(size);
}

int deletion()
{
    int t;
    t=a[1];
    h=a[size--];
    a[1]=h;
    movedown(1);
    return t;
}

void movedown(int i)
{
    int l;
    int r;
    i=2*i;
    r=l+1;
    while(r<=size)
    {
        if(h>a[l]&&h>a[r])
        {
            a[i]=h;
            return;
        }
        else
       {
            if(a[l]>a[r])
            {
                a[i]=a[l];
                i=l;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i]=a[r];
                i=r;
            }
       }
        l=2*i;
        r=l+1;
    }
    if(l<=size&&a[l]>h)
    {
        a[i]=a[l];
        i=l;
    }
    a[i]=h;
    }
```

Comment: In `movedown` the local variable `l` is not initialized. It contains a undetermined value. There are most likely more problems elsewhere in your code. Also check if none of your array indexes is out of bounds. Accessing an array with out of bounds indexes results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: ... also add a typical example of input and expected output. Don't answer in a comment but __[edit]__ your question.

Comment: https://ideone.com/qbxgaZ Compiler warnings. Switch them on.